# How to write bash code to input some content into file and save the file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a bash file to automate the configuration of raspberrypi such as installing the required packages and configuring the static IP address and WIFI network.

the bash file is like:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -f build-essential git libssl-dev
apt-get install -f python-software-properties python g++ make scons
apt-get install -f wpasupplicant
```

I know how to set static IP address manually like this,

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
// save file by ctrl x
reboot
```

but when it comes to setting the static EHO ip address in bash, how can I allow the bash to recognize which line is command , which line is the input in file, how to save the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cat` together with here-doc syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF > /etc/newtwork/interfaces
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
EOF

reboot
```

However, if you router supports static DHCP leases I would set the raspberry to DHCP and configure a static lease on the DHCP server.

Comment: Thanks, hek2mgi,can you tell me the code is to append the file or rewrite the file?

Comment: the code will rewrite the file. If you want to append to the file use `>> /etc/net ...`